# DifficultY process arguments using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: android, batch-file

My code snippet is below:

static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
    {

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "adb.exe ";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    startInfo.Arguments =@"logcat > C:\adb\out.txt";
    Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);          
}
```

The error in my console is:

**Press any key to continue . . . /system/bin/sh: cannot create C:\adb\out.txt: Read-only file system**

It appears it is trying to redirect and save the output on the phone.

When I attempt to run the following from cmd there are no problems at all:

**adb.exe logcat > C:\adb\out.txt**

I am aware I could perform the action inside a batch script, but then I lose a link to the adb.exe process and I wont be able to kill it directly if multiple adb.exe processes exist.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the redirection operand (`>`) if handled by `cmd.exe`. You can not use it if cmd is not involved. Your options are

(1) As you said, runnning a batch file, loosing reference to adb process

(2) Run directly cmd. Your command should look as

`cmd.exe /c "adb.exe logcat > c:\adb\out.txt"`

This removes the batch file but you will loose again the reference to the adb.process

(3) You handle the redirection. Use `startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;` to get the output handle of the adb command, and later call

```
string adbOutput = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```